# MissingServletRequestParameterException not getting caught using @ControllerAdvice

Tags: spring-boot, exception, controller-advice

I'm trying to make a global exception handler, below is the code for that. Other exceptions are getting caught but **MissingServletRequestParameterException** isn't. I tried overriding *handleMissingServletRequestParameter* as well but didn't had much success. Any idea why the exception is not handled?

```
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {Exception.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleOtherExceptions(final Exception ex, final WebRequest req) {

        // handle other exceptions
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. Is your controller advice able to catch any other exceptions? (try throwing deliberately some exception in your controller method)
2. Does `handleOtherExceptions` catches `MissingServletRequestParameterException` exception.

Comment: 1. yes controller advice is able to catch other exceptions like RuntimeException in handleOtherExceptions.
2. no, MissingServletRequestParameterException is not getting caught.